# Were events from the sagas or eddas ever used a precedents at medieval Althings?

Tags: norse, history

The reason I ask is because Snorri, widely regarded as a genius of the first rank by those who know his work, was not only a great poet, but a lawyer and historian, and was twice elected lawspeaker.